# Перенос данных из Interbase в MS SQL Server

Tags: interbase

Есть большая база данных на Interbase, таблицы не связаны между собой. Необходимо всю информацию перенести на MS SQL Server. Перенести необходимо только данные. Процедуры, вьювера и прочее переносить не надо. Подскажите пожалуйста способы реализации поставленной задачи.

Comment: Таблицы - скриптом можно. Процедуры - руцями переписывать. Вьюхи - или первый вариант или второй (зависит от того чистые вьюхи или с informix привязкой)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Перенести нужно только данные.

Comment: Если средствами MSSQL, то там есть "связанные сервера", почитать про них можно тут https://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ff772782(v=sql.105).aspx, это не полностью решит проблему, а облегчит до уровня копипаста `insert into serv1.table1 select * from serv2.table1`. Если нужно что-то другое - уточните что именно вы хотите видеть в ответе (так как решений в лоб нету, есть платные утилиты, есть скриптовые решения для разных языков и платформ свои)

Comment: Изучен большой объем информации и так и не понятно как переносить инфу. Может SSIS. Только перенос нужен будет всего 2 раза - тест и окончательный этап. Просто с Interbase на данный момент работает организация через старую программу. Планируется переход на новую, которая использует ms sql server.